# Angular 2 Pass Data from Component B to the template defined by Component B

Tags: templates, angular, data-binding

I am a little embarrassed to ask this question because I fear the answer is something very obvious, but to me it is illusive.

I have three components A, B & C.  each of these components has a template.
The template of component A contains the custom tag  and of course the template of component B contains a custom tag .

Now I have a chunk of data that needs to flow from component B to C, now if I @Output from B the data is bound to component A template ...  or some such thing.  This dose not make this available to C because the do not share a template.

It seems that I need to be able to "Output" the data to the template on B from component B, but then this would seem circular.  I have looked at Template Reference Variables with @ViewChild but this doesn't seem to be working to make data visible on template B.

Clearly there is something obvious that I have missed, any ideas?

Comment: You can use component properties directly in it's template. If you declare `name` and set it `this.name = 'steve'`, you can display it in the template `{{ name }}`, or pass it to other components `<c [data]="name">`. Is that what you wanted? If not, please provide some code, since it's not clear what you're trying to do...

Comment: @Sasxa ;  many thanks this is in fact exactly correct.  Now that I can be sure this is the correct approach, I can try to figure out why this approach is not working in my specific case.

Comment: @Sasxa;  Once again my thank you for your aid in this problem.   I wanted to add a closing summary note to close any loose ends should anyone come across this question in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To recap... I have three components A, B & C. each of these components has an associated template. The template of component A contains the custom tag `<Bx>` and the template of component Bx contains a custom tag `<C>`.   It is desired to pass a data object from A to C.  This data object is defined in the 'this' scope of component A as "this.data" so the first step in this data transfer is to include an `@Import() data: Obj` in Component B and then add `<B [data]="data"></B>` in the template of A.  This @Import statement makes the this.data available to Component B and which may then be placed on the template of component B as `<C [data]="data"></C>`.

Many thanks to @Sasxa for the guidance, my apologies for the narrative approach but it is the clearest way to explain my situation and resolution.